# How change button enabled true to button enabled false

Tags: vb.net, button

I am currently a novice in the writing language (asp.net_vb) I would like to change button enabled true to button enabled false

I know you write it in (asp.net_C#)

button.enabled=false;

But I do not know how to write in (asp.net_vb)

And I need to be adjusted as soon as

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you kidding? It's just `button.Enabled=False`.

Comment: I've tried before and did not work, but now worked thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this tool to convert C# to Vb.net. you can do it for any of your snippets**

http://converter.telerik.com/

Everything in .Net technology between C# and VB.net is pretty similar. don't get too confuse.

and is this what you're asking for? simple as that !!

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   button1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, it is. there you can convert C# to Vb.net and VB.net to C# back !!